# #CS50 Bubble sort code example not running

Tags: cs50, bubble-sort

Im facing this situtation where I think my code should work yet the cs50 console wont run the code as expected. Would you tell me if you spot the flaw (if any) in my approach??

Whenever I want to run the code, the console stays prompting, and when I tried the debug50 option, it wont print on to the console the now sorted array.

```
#include <stdio.h>
void bubble_sort(int array[], int n);
void swap(int first, int second);
void print_array(int array[], int n);


const  int SIZE = 6;

int main(void)
{
    int  array[] = {2, 1, 3, 6, 4, 5};
    int n = SIZE;
    bubble_sort(array, SIZE);
    printf("Sorted array: \n");
    print_array(array, SIZE);
}



void swap(int first, int second)
{
    int container = first;
    first = second;
    second = container;
}


void bubble_sort(int array[], int n)
{
    int counter = 1;
    do
    {
        counter = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
        {
            if (array[i] > array[i + 1])
            {
                swap(array[i], array[i + 1]);
                counter += 1;
            }
        }
    }
    while (counter > 0);
}


void print_array(int array[], int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("%i ", array[i]);
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: You might get more help from `https://cs50.stackexchange.com/` as it is the official CS50 SE.

Comment: The `while counter > 0` looks like an infinite loop waiting to happen.

Answer (score 0):

This is the pseudocode of the bubble sort, as presented in the lecture 3 of the course:

```
Repeat n–1 times
    For i from 0 to n–2
        If i'th and i+1'th elements out of order
            Swap them
```

Try to implement this pseudocode.